# Is there an Excel Formula to sum two cells if the ID is duplicated?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a list of projects that are either Capex or Opex. If the project is Capex, it needs to use the Forecasted value, and if the project is Opex, it needs to use the Planned value. BUT, there are some projects that are both, which means it needs to SUM the Forecasted value from the Capex entry and Planned from Opex. Is there an excel formula or VBA module I can use to easily do this without making it manual?

Here is an example of the data:

[image: example]

So in this case, there would be a column to the right with the values 1000, 2000, and 3000 respectively.

Comment: SUMIF and/or SUMIFS

Comment: Have a look at the [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

Comment: `it needs to SUM the Forecasted value from the Capex entry and Planned from Opex` - and place it where? To the capex entry or to the opex entry? Or to both, in which case it is double accounting? Or to a third line?

Comment: *"So in this case, there would be a column to the right with the values 1000, 2000, and 3000 respectively."* - where are those numbers coming from?

Comment: @dwirony 1000 from forecasted for project 100, 2000 from planned for project 200, 3000 from sum of forecasted and planned for project 300.

Comment: @GSerg I see now... I was having a hard time following! :)

Comment: If there can be up to two instances of the same project in the table, if it is guaranteed that they belong to different types, and if each instance must show the total for the two rows, then `=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$B$2:$B$5,"OPEX",$A$2:$A$5,$A2)+SUMIFS($D$2:$D$5,$B$2:$B$5,"CAPEX",$A$2:$A$5,$A2)`, provided Project ID is in A1.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is, as others have mentioned it's called the [SUMIF](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) function. As it sounds, it sums all the values to which the critera applied is TRUE.

However, in your example, I don't think the SUMIF function would be very useful. Rather, a carefully crafted nest of IF and IFS would solve your issue. In your example, it looks like you would SUM the values together IF 'project x' is found at least one place else in the data, AND that alternate 'project x' is of the alternate type (CAPEX vs OPEX).

I'm assuming you have a basic knowledge of the functions I'll implement in this example, so I'll spare you the details - just know that I use the TEXTJOIN funciton to create column E, which I use as a way to check if the alternate identity (Project 3OPEX vs Project 3CAPEX) exists somewhere in the sheet. If it does, the columns F and G are summed; if not, data is used from either column F or G, depending on the Type (Column D)[image: Example of formula]

Comment: Alternatively, instead of IFS, you could also use a SWITCH() formula. For example, SWITCH(<Name>, CAPEX, IF(<AlternateIDFound>,3000,1000), OPEX, IF(<AlternateIDFound>,3000,2000), <default value (probably " ")>)